# autodecrement in number using c#

Tags: c#

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1265914403006619100.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1265914403006619100.jpg)

How do I autodecrement the number of students allowed everytime you assign a section to each student added?

I have the code, but it has an error.

```
    private void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////for auto increment
        ds = DBConn.getStudentDetails("sp_Retrieve_Student_Section");
        int cnt = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        string lastrec = ds.Tables[0].Rows[cnt+1][1].ToString();
        int newpcode = int.Parse(lastrec) - 1;
        txtAllowed.Text= newpcode.ToString();



    }
```

Comment: psst, don't use sp as the prefix for your stored procs.

Comment: You've already asked this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242053/how-to-autoincrement-in-c) and many others (http://stackoverflow.com/users/252490/malou17) related to it.

Comment: its more than as an assignment... well dont worry i'm not asking you to do it for me..i'm just asking for help why i cannot autodecremnt the number

Comment: Jason is correct, I remember seeing a very similar question by a similarly lost individual asking it.  The SO community is always ready to help, even in very didactic ways when it comes to newbies/homework-like questions.  Never the less I suggest we close this question, for itself lack detail and thoughtfulness.  It would be akin to someone stringing together a few words in a foreign tongue and expecting others to help them write a book in said tongue.

Comment: well that link is for autoincrement and not autodecrement

Comment: @malou: Why the new account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/252490

Comment: what u mean why the new accout

Comment: @malou: `autoincrement and not autodecrement`...  my point, exactly! This type of remark or the vague description of the `highlighted line of code` indicate that you do not master basic programming skills and concepts and yet you keep pushing along.  Instead I suggest to take a step back and take the time to understand these, rather than keeping asking for help on very localized and very ill-structured snippets of code, to perform very poorly defined actions upon undefined structures...  I do not mean to insult you in any way, maybe you never had a chance to establish these fundations...

Comment: @malou: Ok then. Good luck on that thesis...

Comment: @malou:... I just want to encourage you to build such fundations first.  A little bit like with my writing a book in a foreign tongue example, one should first learn a few words of vocabury, the general structure of the grammar, etc. before trying to create a best seller or even to write a 5 pages memo...

Comment: @mjv: yeah i know... its is just that im not into programming...im more on into multimedia...i just have this thesis becuase of my subject course

Answer (score 3):

At first glance it looks like this line:

```
string lastrec = ds.Tables[0].Rows[cnt+1][1].ToString();
```

cnt+1 is out of the bounds of the collection, and an exception probably told you this.  You are probably looking for cnt-1.

Comment: everytime i run the system.... it appears higlighted line code


int newpcode = int.Parse(lastrec) - 1;

Comment: it appears highlighted code in the system telling that i have an error in my codes

Comment: Pretty sure that's what she was asking. What are the errors you are receiving. Telling us where you receive the error but not what the error is doesn't help a whole lot.

Comment: There is no row at position 6.

Comment: @malou: Then I suggest you re-read this answer as blu both explains why that error would occur **AND** how to solve it. Not only that but he did it through mind reading so +1 to him for sure.

Comment: i already change my cnt+1 to cnt-1

Comment: @malou: Then your error message has changed. If you expect further help you should edit your question to show the changed code and describe the new error message you are receiving.

Comment: just edidted it


    
      private void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ////for auto increment
            ds = DBConn.getStudentDetails("sp_Retrieve_Student_Section");
            int cnt = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            string lastrec = ds.Tables[0].Rows[cnt-1][1].ToString();
            int newpcode = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(lastrec, out newpcode))
            {
                newpcode--;
            }

            txtAllowed.Text= newpcode.ToString();



        }

Comment: there is no errror appear...its just that when i select the combobox for their section the number of students 40 becomes 0.

Comment: "Rows[cnt+1][1]" - Check the value that is returned by this column [1] (the collection is zero based).  It sounds like your new error is lastrec is not a number in a string.

Comment: i just change Rows[cnt+1][1] to [cnt-1][1]

and it appears if the student is 40 then assign their serction it becomes 0 already

Comment: heres the image link
first it was set on 40
http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1265914403006619100.jpg

and when i tried to assign Hope, 40 becomes 0 already

http://www.imagechicken.com/viewcode.php?p=1265942275045572000&x=jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write

```
 int newpcode = int.Parse(lastrec) - 1;
```

as

```
int newpcode = 0;
if(Int32.TryParse(lastrec, out newpcode))
{
   newpcode--;
}
```

That way, if it can successfully parse the lastrec, it will decrement.
If it can't successfully parse, your newpcode will be 0, but will not throw an error.

Comment: when i rewrite my code

into your code and try it run... when i assign a section in the combo box.. the number of student becamse 0

Comment: @malou: That's because you don't understand the basics of what you are trying to do. The error message you describe in blu's answer point to that being the problem and not what taylonr is describing. Sorry to be so blunt.

Comment: already change my errors
@ Cory: sorry for vague questions and answers..well thats the thing it is higlighted anyway i just gave the error message saying there is no row in line 6

Comment: Didn't see that error message in the comments on Blu's answer... if the error is "there is no row in line 6" then that's definitely point to Blu's answer.  If you're always getting set to 0, then that means lastrec is unable to be parsed into an int.